# Hex-Rays function signature does not match demangled name

Tags: ida, arm, hexrays, strings

From the demangled name, I know that a function takes an `std::string const&` as a parameter but when generating psuedo-c code with Hex-Rays' decompiler it autodetects the parameters as `(int a1, int a2, int a3)`

How can I fix the function signature Hex-Rays' is generating?

[image: screenshot of IDA graph view]

```
int __fastcall EncodeUtil::getDecryptStr(int a1, int a2, int a3)
{
  int v3; // r7
  unsigned int i; // r5
  char v5; // r6
  int v7; // [sp+4h] [bp-1Ch]
  int v8; // [sp+8h] [bp-18h]

  v7 = a2;
  v8 = a3;
  v3 = a1;
  HttpUtility::URLDecode(&v7);
  for ( i = 0; i < *(_DWORD *)(v7 - 12); ++i )
  {
    sub_3B25D0(&v7);
    v5 = byte_41A7DD[i & 7];
    *(_BYTE *)(v7 + i) ^= v5;
    sub_3B25D0(&v7);
    if ( !*(_BYTE *)(v7 + i) )
    {
      sub_3B25D0(&v7);
      *(_BYTE *)(v7 + i) ^= v5;
    }
  }
  sub_3B2E20(v3, &v7);
  sub_3B1CCC(&v7);
  return v3;
}
```

Comment: It looks like they have different calling conventions.

Comment: @armnostrong: You should have specified that you are dealing with ARM targets...

Comment: @armnotstrong: Do you know what compiler was used? The structure of an std::string is going to vary wildly based upon that

Comment: @Avery3R all I know is that this was a project of [cocos2dx](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) compiled for android device

Comment: @perror sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like hex-rays mistakenly thought there were three parameters instead of two. If you look at the start of the function's disassembly `R1` and `R2` are not saved, only `R0` is. You should be able to just change the function signature to `int __fastcall EncodeUtil::getDecryptStr(void* pString)`. The default key to do so is `Y`. If you have a struct definition for `std::string` you can replace the `void*` in the signature with an `std::string*`

Comment: FYI `PUSH {R0-R2}` saves R0, R1 and R2.

Comment: Ah yeah, I meant saved in another register to be used within this function later, like it did with `MOV R7, R0`. `R1` and `R2` are definitely used somewhere in this function later, but I'm willing to bet they're assigned to first before they're read from.